# Convert latitude and longitude into PFGeoPoint in swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, geolocation

In objective-c we can convert a latitude and longitude to a PFGeoPoint using geoPointWithLatitude.
But i couldn't find any method to do it in swift.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use this code. may be help you.

```
var descLocation: PFGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint()

descLocation.latitude = coord.latitude
descLocation.longitude = coord.longitude
```